# Python coverage when using subprocess won't work

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to get coverage report in python3 when subprocess is involved, but I'm only getting coverage of the main process, not the subprocess.

I'm running on Linux, and using Python 3.7.1 (yes, I know it's on old version, but this is the environment that the code has to work on). The version of coverage that I am using is 7.2.7.

Here is the code for the "main"...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import subprocess


process = subprocess.Popen(["python3", "child.py"],
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

i = 0
for line in process.stdout:
    line = line.decode().rstrip()
    print(line)

    if i < 10:
        i += 1
    else:
        break

process.terminate()
process.wait()
```

Here is the code for the "child" process...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import time
import random

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print(random.randint(0, 10), flush=True)
```

I have followed the instructions [here](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/7.3.1/subprocess.html).

I have a "config" file (.coveragerc) with the following...

```
[run]
branch = True
parallel = True
concurrency = thread, multiprocessing
```

Note, I tried with / without the concurrency line to see if it made difference, it didn't.

I have environment variable `COVERAGE_PROCESS_START` set to point to the .coveragerc config file

I have `sitecustomize.py` file configure in site directory with the following...

```
import coverage
coverage.process_startup()
```

I also had a "print" statement in the above file so I could see that it was being run and called when subprocess started.

I run the "main" like this: `coverage run main.py`

To get the report I do: `coverage combine` and then `coverage report`

Note, before I did the "combine" I can see that there is only one coverage.* file, clearly there should be at least 2 if it's working properly.

But, I only see the coverage for "main"...

```
Name      Stmts   Miss Branch BrPart  Cover
-------------------------------------------
main.py      12      0      4      1    94%
-------------------------------------------
TOTAL        12      0      4      1    94%
```

What am I doing wrong? I've been going round in circles forever on this thing!

PS: I know there are possible duplicates for this question, e.g. [Run coverage on test with subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72263042/run-coverage-on-test-with-subprocess), [Python coverage subprocess coverage.process_startup() error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60736080/python-coverage-subprocess-coverage-process-startup-error), etc. I've read them, and followed the answers, but it is still not working in my case.

New information:
I just found that if I make the "child" process terminate early (using a loop counter) it works! My conclusion is that coverage is not handling the condition where the subprocess is terminated. According to [documentation](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/7.3.1/subprocess.html#process-termination) it should handle both atexit() and SIGTERM. I've verified that SIGTERM is received in child when the main does process.terminate().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question here.

So, I was doing everything correctly above. The issue is that coverage.py was not writing the data when the "child" process received SIGTERM like it is supposed to do (at least in version 6.3 or newer). See ['No data to report' when i execute coverage report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67656307/no-data-to-report-when-i-execute-coverage-report) for this hint.

Reading the [docs](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/6.2/subprocess.html#signal-handlers-and-atexit) for version 6.2, when SIGTERM was not supported - it suggests adding a signal handler to catch SIGTERM and then exit normally. If I do this to the child process - it works!

Here's the modified child process code...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import time
import random
import signal

def signal_handler(number, frame):
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)

i = 0
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print(random.randint(0, 10), flush=True)
```

Now, after running main.py and doing the combine & report...

```
Name       Stmts   Miss Branch BrPart  Cover
--------------------------------------------
child.py      11      0      0      0   100%
main.py       14      0      4      1    94%
--------------------------------------------
TOTAL         25      0      4      1    97%
```

It works - but requires code modification.

But there's a better solution!

It turns out that the support for SIGTERM handling was added as an option, and disabled by default! See [here](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/7.3.1/config.html#run-sigterm).

So, I need to modify the .coveragerc file...

```
[run]
branch = True
parallel = True
sigterm = True
```

And then it works as it is supposed to do.